# Static web project is missing on Eclipse oxygen

Tags: eclipse, web, eclipse-oxygen

I'm a newbie in CS. I've eclipse oxygen installed but when I go to File -> New I don't see Static Web Project. My older laptop had Eclipse Neon and it had Static, Dynamic as well as Project / Java Project.

Comment: Oxygen is a release version, and each release comes assembled in different packages. Which download did you start from for Oxygen?

Comment: Seems you are missing the "Web Tools Platform", try installing it from marketplace.

Comment: There's more than one way. https://wiki.eclipse.org/WTP_FAQ#How_do_I_install_WTP.3F